# Meu package.json está dando erro!

Tags: node.js, visual-studio

Estou tento problemas com meu package.json. Está dando erro direto, e quando abro o node para fazer o arquivo, também dá erro como mostra as fotos anexadas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se voce deseja criar um arquivo `package.json`, voce deve executar o comando:

```
npm init -yes
```

Isso vai criar um package.json padrão.

Se quiser é possível utilizar o modo iterativo, para gerar de acordo com algumas perguntas que são feitas via linha de comando.

Para isso basta usar o comando:

```
npm init
```

Se deseja saber mais sobre o como criar um arquivo `package.json` e outras opções de uso, pode acessar a [documentação](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file).